# iOS 7 layer transform on z axis has different behavior than on iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, core-animation, calayer, catransform3d

I can't figured out an issue I have between iOS 7 and iOS 8 with the layer transform 3D.

In my own application, I'm trying to reproduce the spotify side menu 3D effect.
Nevertheless this effect is working perfectly on iOS 8, but not on iOS 7.

For those who don't know which effect I'm talking about?
You can scroll the main view from left to the right. At the same time the scrolling occur, the table view menu will perform a transformation on both x and z axis.

I found that the z axis of my CATransform3D has a different behavior on iOS 7.

Here are some screen captures. (Screen1: [iOS 8 - Normal behavior], Screen 2: [iOS 7 - Incorrect behavior])

[image: iOS 8 - Normal behavior]
[image: iOS 7 - Incorrect behavior]

Here is the code I wrote to perform this effect.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
CGFloat subWidth = self.scrollView.subviewWidth;
CGFloat alpha = (((subWidth - scrollView.contentOffset.x) * 100.0f) / subWidth) / 100.0f;

// setup the alpha for the table view
self.tableView.alpha = alpha;

// perform the tableview 3D transform
CGFloat axe = 50.0f - (50.0f * alpha);

CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity;
t.m34 = 1.0f / -250.0f;
t = CATransform3DTranslate(t, axe, 0.0f, -axe);

self.tableView.layer.transform = t;}
```

***subWidth*** is the space between the main view and the left border of the screen."

What I can't figured out is, why the table view has not the same position 
at the end of the transformation ?